# Html5gallery.js Not working in Razor view for MVC 4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new to MVC4 and I am creating video gallery using Razor view of MVC4 
using Html5gallery.js ,I have first implemented this in aspx page and its working fine but when i use it with Razor view its not working..

Code for Index.cshtml page :

```
@using  MvcPhotoGallery.Models
@model IEnumerable<Photo>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/html5gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   
}
<h2></h2>
<legend> Gallery</legend>
<div style="display:none;" class="html5gallery"  data-skin="showcase" data-width="480" data-height="272">
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    @*  <a href=item.><img src=  alt="big back"/></a>*@
    <a href="@item.ImageURL"> <img src="@item.ImageSRC" /></a>
}
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Please Help!!! Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove master page link from code.
Please refer below workind code

```
@using  MvcPhotoGallery.Models
@model IEnumerable<Photo>
@{
  Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/html5gallery.js"></script>    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div style="display:none;" class="html5gallery"  data-skin="showcase" data-         width="480" data-height="272">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            @*  <a href=item.><img src=  alt="big back"/></a>*@

            <a href="@item.ImageURL"> <img src="@item.ImageSRC" alt="aaa" /></a>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try put the `script` tags in the bottom of the page, rather than in top of the page, and it will be rendered at last instead of at first.

Comment: Albus Shin:Thanks,I have tried it but still it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried to take the `script` tags out of the `@{}` section? Also, if `jquery.js` and `html5gallery.js` is in the root directory, you can use UrlHelper to generate url from `"/Scripts/html5gallery.js"`. Have you seen any bugs from the console of the browser(s)?

Answer (score 0):

All the code that you write in `@{ }` block is executing by Razor View Engine when it forms your web page. You can't reference client scripts in that block. So you need to write script references outside of it.
Better way to reference script should be scrips section. Check if you have one on the bottom of `~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`. It looks like this:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Then on your view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@section scripts {
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/html5gallery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```